# How to copy none sequential data to a GPU memory buffer in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I know how i would copy a array from Host to GPU. But what happens if i have a column major matrix stored on host that i want to copy to a buffer on the GPU.

Are there other ways then copying one element at the time in a forloop ?

A_host [0 3 6 
        1 4 7
        2 5 8].

GPUBuffer = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, and if the matrix is sufficiently large, you may want to send it "as-is" to the GPU, and insert an additional transpose kernel (or merge it to your first kernel).

Comment: Is it a normal process to create multiply kernels for the same task for cases like this to avoid situations where a transpose is needed or memory being copied? In a different setting i had 60.000 x 784 matrix where i needed to copy 100 rows to the GPU, i just copied 100 times in a forloop. should i consider to extract the memory on host and only query one copy command?